# How can I solve HandshakeException when use https connection using flutter in iOS platform?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I'm using SecurityContext class for configure HttpClient.

```
Future<HttpClient> _crearClienteHttp() async{
     ByteData certificadoSerializado = await rootBundle.load('assets/certificados/' + CERTIFICADO_SSL);
     SecurityContext contextoSeguridad = SecurityContext(withTrustedRoots: true);

     contextoSeguridad.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(certificadoSerializado.buffer.asUint8List());

     return HttpClient(context: contextoSeguridad);
}
```

The returned HttpClient work with https successfully in Android Emulator and Android Device,
but in iOS emulator I always obtain "HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: ok(handshake.cc:354))".

In the past I got a similar error in Android but unlike this error that says "ok (handshake.cc:354)", I received more specific error.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in all my projects to solve this problem

```
void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = new MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

const String domain = "www.your_domain_name.com";

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => host == domain;
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be a solution, but it does not verify the certificate. I don't understand why the code work successfully in Android and it does not function in iOS. Maybe I'm missing some configuration in iOS.